# Регулярное выражение, определяющее является ли данная строка шестнадцатеричным идентификатором цвета в HTML

Tags: html, python, регулярные-выражения, импорт, match

Дана задача:

Написать регулярное выражение, определяющее
является ли данная строка шестнадцатеричным идентификатором цвета в HTML,
где `#FFFFFF` –  белый цвет, `#000000` – черный, `#FF0000` – красный и т.д.

Примеры правильных выражений: `#FFFFFF`, `#FF3421`, `#00ff00`.
Примеры неправильных выражений: `232323`, `f#fddee`, `#fd2`.

Мой код:

```
import re
a = re.match (r'[0-9A-Fa-f]{6}', input('Введите проверяемую строку: '))
if a == None:
    print('Строка не является идентификатором цвета')
else:
    print('Введенная строка - идентификатор цвета')
```

Почему оно работает наоборот? Когда a = None, то оно должно выводить отрицательный ответ, а выводит положительный. Аналогично для обратного.

Comment: У вас регулярка неправильная

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re
a = re.match (r'#[0-9A-Fa-f]{6}', input('Введите проверяемую строку: '))
if a is None : ## правка @cppquestions
    print('Строка не является идентификатором цвета')
else:
    print('Введенная строка - идентификатор цвета')
```

Comment: Чем это отличается от кода автора?

Comment: `#[0-9A-Fa-f]{6}` вместо `[0-9A-Fa-f]{6}`

Comment: А, заметил. Дополните тогда, что тут ошибка в сравнении через ==, а не is

Comment: @cppquestions почему ошибка? Существуют ситуации, когда None не будет равен None?

Comment: @andreymal ссылаюсь на [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48504780/10743113). Возможно, в этом случае нет разницы

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

pattern = re.compile('#[0-9A-Fa-f]{6}$')
a = input('Введите проверяемую строку: ')

if pattern.match(a):
    print('Введенная строка - идентификатор цвета')
else:
    print('Строка не является идентификатором цвета')
```

---

*Объяснение:*

Важно обеспечить, чтобы не определить например строку `#123456789` как *правильный* идентификатор цвета, хотя его начало - `#123456` - совсем правильное.

Потому в конце регулярного выражения символ `$` - конец строки.

Comment: А начало строки проверить?

Comment: @Qwertiy - начало строки не нужно проверить, т.к. применяется  `match()`, а не `search()`.